# Как мне раскинуть текст в класах menu-left и menu-right по сторонам

Tags: html, css, frontend

я не могу раскинуть текст по разным бокам  сайта. Kак мне расположить текст по углам сайта в классах menu-right и menu-left ?

Answer (score 2):

ну например так:

```
.menu-left {
    float:left;
}

.menu-right {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.menu-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}


/* раскидываем */

.menu-right span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.menu-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #0f1a31;
  color: white;
}


/* раскидываем */

.menu-left span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-right">
  <span>TEST R</span>
</div>

<div class="menu-left">
  <span>TEST L</span>
</div>
```

То чем ты занимешься не КОДИНГ

Comment: не кодинг, а верстка